# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I am getting error : `HTTP Status 404`
with warning of :

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/p2/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'HelloWeb'
```

following are my files :

HelloController.java

```
package pack1;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      //model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      return "hello";
   }

}
```

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="pack1" />

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to add method "hello" into your HelloController

Comment: How do you call your controller?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `@RequestMapping("/p2")` for the controller as shown below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/p2")
public class HelloController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
      //model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");
      return "hello";
   }
}
```

Comment: i changed to @RequestMapping("/p2") but still giving same error